# Is there a way to use saved model between different versions of H2O?

Tags: r, deployment, machine-learning, deep-learning, h2o

I have saved a trained model (deep net, but it is more general I think) in [H2O](http://www.h2o.ai/product/). Now I want to load it by another instance of H2O and use it for scoring, but the problem is, that the version of H2O used for training (`3.10.0.3`) was different than the one I started the production cluster with (`3.10.0.6`). The error message is quite self-explanatory

```
ERROR MESSAGE:

Found version 3.10.0.3, but running version 3.10.0.6
```

Is there a way to migrate the saved model between versions? Or am I stuck with using the same version of H2O for training and scoring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are stuck using the same version for training and scoring. No migration route.

(You can export a model as a POJO, which can be bundled with the version of h2o-genmodel.jar that it needs. But that requires writing Java code to get the data in and results out, which is not ideal if you are using R code for data preparation.)

This has been discussed on the h2o-stream mailing list before, but I couldn't see a feature request ticket for it, so I just created one: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3432

Comment: I know about the POJO, I just wanted to get back to old model, but cluster is already running new version. Thanks for the ticket. Will keep an eye on it.

Comment: @JaKu I'd keep expectations low - I got the impression it was not going to happen unless lots of people (H2O's paying customers in particular) start asking for it.  (I.e. developers, whatever the project, love the flexibility to change binary formats, and not have to worry about backwards compatibility.)

Comment: @JaKu (and anyone else interested) I got frustrated by this again, so tried to hack my way round it, but failed. I added a comment to the ticket. If you vote and/or comment there I think it is more likely to get addressed.

Comment: I have version 3.15.0.4050 on my AWS and 3.15.4052 on my mac, and I cant make  the mac read the AWS generated model and cannot find the right version of h2o to install on the mac. frustrating.

Comment: @WoodyPride It seems in the past year that ticket has got exactly zero votes. Personally this is my biggest complaint about H2O, but obviously not the case for other people.    BTW, I think all releases are to be found on S3... can't seem to find the URL at the moment, though.